# How to manipulate List object or an array that will enable to calculate the Sum, Average, Count?

Tags: c#, winforms

inside the **calcBtn_Click** event handler, how do I write code that will display the **individual elements of the array on a MessageBox?** For example, a List object named scores contains test scores entered by the user. On a MessageBox, how do I display the content of the array one by one? (Item 1 : 90 + "\n" + Item 2 : 85....)

*General Description:*
This is a program that I have to write for class. Its purpose is to calculate test scores. It will take user input from the "Enter number of exams" text box and assign it as a length property of an array. Then, the program will prompt the user to enter the scores of the above-mentioned number of scores, one by one. Then, the program will display the individual scores (e.g: Exam 1: 90, Exam 2: 75....) and also display the total score and average. How would I accomplish this by using List and not a 1D array? Please help, thanks!

I have attached the image link of the GUI in case anybody will need to see what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ArrayTestCalculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private void calcBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            total = scores.Sum();
            MessageBox.Show(total.ToString("n"));

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the question and problem description? Also you should provide only code related to your problem. Do not copy-paste whole text of your program.

Comment: You already using List but asking to replace the Array with List so it is not clear

Comment: Sorry I'm a new user to Stack, I have specified my issue above and only added  the code that I think I have problems on.

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

you would need to convert the data you want to show to a string

```
string toDisplay = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, array); 
MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);
```